# Adding meeting action points in MediaWiki and viewing them in another page

Tags: templates, mediawiki

In the minutes of a meeting we want to be able to place action points in the text.  Then we want easily to be able to print a list of action points, e.g. via another page.

So the minutes will be:

blah blah blah #AP1 ... blah blah blah #AP2... blah

And then we want a list like this:

#AP1

#AP2

How would we do this?  Is there e.g. a solution with templates or an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without an extension, though the syntax is a bit verbose - probably can simplified further for ease of note-taking.

- Example meeting notes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Jlerner/SandboxNotes
- Action items derived from above: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Jlerner/SandboxActionItems

Comment: That's very clever Joshua, thanks.

In case you later delete (for the benefit of others) Joshua has:

blah blah blah <onlyinclude><includeonly>
</includeonly>#AP1 blah</onlyinclude> ... blah blah blah <onlyinclude><includeonly>
</includeonly>#AP2 blah</onlyinclude>... blah

on his user notes page (the record of the meeting) and only

{{User:Jlerner/SandboxNotes}}

on his action items page.

Comment: Here are the permanent links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=User:Jlerner/SandboxNotes&oldid=357835384


http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=User:Jlerner/SandboxActionItems&oldid=357835550

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution we've come up with is using references - that way the action points are separated but we can still see the context.

However, this is not really sufficient.  We want to print ONLY the action points and so (we think) we need a separate page for the action points.