# Is there a way to get </onlyinclude> included onto a MediaWiki page via a template?

Tags: templates, wiki, mediawiki

I want to [add action points to a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698294/adding-meeting-action-points-in-mediawiki-and-viewing-them-in-another-page) via a template. This requires that the page with the action points contains this code:

```
<onlyinclude><includeonly>
</includeonly>#AP1 blah</onlyinclude> ... blah blah blah <onlyinclude><includeonly>
</includeonly>#AP2 blah</onlyinclude>... blah
```

But I want this via a template, so that a user only has to add something like:

```
{{subst:Action point|<action>}}
```

using the template: `{{Action point}}`.

The problem is adding the `</onlyinclude>` to a page. I can add `<onlyinclude>` using:

```
`<onlyinclude><onlyinclude></onlyinclude>`
```

I've tried adding hidden comments, using `<noinclude>` and `<includeonly>` but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas? The solution I'm looking for is where (as the above link explains) I can add text (meeting minutes) with action points on one page, and on another view *only* the action points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a monstrous hack, but it works.   You will need a recent version of MediaWiki that supports `safesubst:`.

1. Create the page `Template:Startinclude` with the content `<onlyinclude><onlyinclude></onlyinclude>`.
2. Create the page `Template:Endinclude` with the content `</onlyinclude>`.
3. Create the page `Template:Ap` with this content:

> ```
> Head
> <includeonly>{{safesubst:Startinclude}}</includeonly>
> Body
> <includeonly>{{safesubst:Endinclude}}</includeonly>
> Foot
> ```

And now `{{subst:Ap}}` expands to this:

> ```
> Head
> <onlyinclude>
> Body
> </onlyinclude>
> Foot
> ```

For a live demo, enter `{{subst:User:Jpatokal/Ap}}` on any Wikipedia page, it uses [this template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aJpatokal/Ap).

Comment: Great, it works! Here's a link to [safesubst](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Substitution#Multilevel_substitution). (I need to wait until I can award the bounty...)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `&lt;onlyinclude>` and `&lt;/onlyinclude>` work just as well as `<onlyinclude><onlyinclude></onlyinclude>` and `</only<noinclude></noinclude>include>`?

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the following trick, within the template in order to transclude and substitute `<onlyinclude>` or `<noinclude>`:

```
<{{{fwd|onlyinclude}}}>Some text...</{{{fwd|onlyinclude}}}>
Some text...
<{{{fwd|noinclude}}}>Some text...</{{{fwd|noinclude}}}>
```

After the substitution the `{{{fwd|}}}` variable will be expanded at its place with the default value and you will get the desired tags. I'm using *fwd* as shortcut of *forward*, but you could choice different name.

Here is how to insert a category in to a page by template substitution using this approach - the template content should be:

```
<{{{fwd|noinclude}}}><includeonly>[[Category:CatName|?]]</includeonly></{{{fwd|noinclude}}}>
```